# Get (main)parent id in extjs treeview

Tags: extjs

[TreeView Extjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJj7Y.png)

As shown in the above image , if Node-1.2.3.1.1 is checked , how do i get the Id of Node-1.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should navigate through the tree structure via the [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface).
You have have access to `parentNode` and `childNodes` property.

So I suggest to do a recursive function to find your top node.
It should like:

```
function findRootParent(node) {
    var parentNode = node.parentNode;

    // wrong case (if you give the root node for example)
    if(!parentNode) {
        return null; // or self 
    }

    // we've found it!
    if(node.parentNode.isRoot())
        return node;
    // go recursive
    return findRootParent(node.parentNode);
}
```

And when you've found the parent, you can check `isExpanded()` or not